# Setting Rails time zone in an initializer does not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, config

Since Rails 5 the *application.rb* tells me to place my app's configuration in initializers. In order to follow this convention, I wanted to set my timezone in an initializer.

*config/initializers/time_zone.rb*

```
Rails.application.config.time_zone = "Paris"
```

Rails seems to ignore this setting and keeps its default time zone. Using the same code inside of my *application.rb* works. Why is the initializer being ignored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [Rails5 guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) it should be configured in `config/application.rb` file.

```
#application.rb
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.time_zone = 'Paris'
end
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I thought all the configuration should possibly go in initializers.

Comment: The note in the ```application.rb``` stating that all configs should go in initializers is incorrect. There is a commit pending on this as at 11 Feb 2017.

Comment: @RichardHulse Can you show what about you are talking?

Comment: Here is the related issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24748. Read to end of page for details.

Comment: @RichardHulse yes here also telling that timezone should be in application.rb file  cause in initializers it's having issues. Thanks !